# Existance of monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that:

1. There exists a monomorphism $D_{4} \rightarrow S_{4}$;
2. There is no monomorphism $Q_{8} \rightarrow S_{4}$.

I think I can do the second example. My idea is to show that there are more elements of order 2 in $S_{4}$ than there are in $Q_{8}$. Is it correct? Any ideas about the first monomorphism?

Comment: Note that existence of a monomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is equivalent to $H$ containing a subgroup isomorphic to $G$. For 1, you can view $D_4$ as a group of (certain) permutations on 2 or 4 vertices (depending on the definition of $D_4$). Thus it must equal some subgroup of $S_4$, the group of (all) permutations on 4 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the first is true. Let D be generated by $r,f$ where they denote reflection by 90 and flip. Then sending $r$ into $(1324)$ and $f$ to $(12)$ does the job. Actualy $S_4$ has $3$ copies of $D_4$. Find them all.

As for second, there is none. as all three subgroups of order $8$ in $S_4$ are isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: Notice that a subgroup of order $8$ in $S_4$ is a sylow $2$ subgroup so you can count them to be exactly $3$

Comment: Reflection by 90? What do you mean?

Comment: $R_{90}$ in $D_4$. You represent elements of $D_4$ by symmeteries of a square right. If you are only working with presentation or formal definition then take  $D_4= <r,f|r^4=f^2=1,f^{-1}rf=r^{-1}>$. same thing. $r$ can be any element of order $4$ in $D_4$, and there are only two such.